# Cookies for different domains showing under the one URL in Application -> Storage -> Cookies

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I have two apps running locally:

1. Identity Server (localhost:44349)
2. ASP.NET Client app (127.0.0.1:44300)

I've set up a binding to access the client app using the home IP address in order to prevent cookies from one app being sent to the other app.

However I've noticed in **DevTools -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies**, they are all listed under 127.0.0.1:

[image]

I have noticed the cookies are being sent correctly, ie. Identity Server cookies are not being sent when making requests to the client app and vice versa.

Does it matter that all cookies are listed under 127.0.0.1?

Shouldn't Chrome DevTools list them separately since they are being sent to different URLs?

Comment: Might be a bug/oversight in devtools.